# How to perform a multi Pauli rotation with arbitary angle?

Tags: surface-code, state-distillation, magic-states, postselection

Recently, I was trying to find some methods to perform a multi Pauli rotation gate with arbitary angle. I want to use the method proposed in the paper arXiv:1808.02892v3, and the circuit is shown as follow. Since the figure in the paper seems incomplete, I haven't been able to fully derive the equivalence between this circuit and the quantum gate $e^{i\phi P}$.

My question is:

**1. Is there any thing wrong in the process of my derivation?**

**2. If not using this method, is there any more efficient method to perform this gate?**

**Notice that this method is in the context of fault-tolerant computation, we can only perform Clifford gates and consume some non-Clifford state $|\phi\rangle,|2\phi\rangle,|4\phi\rangle...$**

[image]

Here are some definiton:

$e^{i\phi P} = \cos{\phi}I + i\sin{\phi}P$ is a multi Pauli rotation gate, where $P=P_1\otimes P_2\otimes P_3\otimes ...\otimes P_n$ is tensor product of n Pauli matrixes and $\phi \in [0,2\pi)$ is an arbitary real number. Now suppose we have a n-qubit state $|\Psi\rangle=\sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^n}a_x|x\rangle=\sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^n}a_x|x_1^{(P_1)}x_2^{(P_2)}...x_n^{(P_n)}\rangle$, where $x_k^{(P_k)}$ is the k-th bit in string $x$, and the superscript $(P_k)$ means we decompose the k-th qubit of $\Psi$ into the basis of $P_k$. For example, if $P = X\otimes Z\otimes Z$, then $|0^{(X)}0^{(Z)}1^{(Z)}\rangle$ means basis $|+\rangle|0\rangle|1\rangle$. One benefit to do so is to further combine the component of $\Psi$. That is, $|\Psi\rangle=\sum_{\sum x_k \text{ is even}}a_x|x\rangle + \sum_{\sum x_k \text{ is odd}}a_x|x\rangle$, and $e^{i\phi P}|\Psi\rangle = \sum_{\sum x_k \text{ is even}}a_x|x\rangle + e^{-2i\phi}\sum_{\sum x_k \text{ is odd}}a_x|x\rangle$ up to some global phase.

$|\phi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + e^{i(2\phi)}|1\rangle)$

So here are my derivation:

Initialization:

$|\Psi\rangle|\phi\rangle|2\phi\rangle|4\phi\rangle = 
(\sum_e a_x|x\rangle + \sum_o a_x|x\rangle)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + e^{i(2\phi)}|1\rangle) |2\phi\rangle |4\phi\rangle$

After applying $\Lambda(P,Z_1Z_2Z_3)$:

$\sum_e a_x|x\rangle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + e^{i(2\phi)}|1\rangle) |2\phi\rangle |4\phi\rangle + \sum_o a_x|x\rangle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle - e^{i(2\phi)}|1\rangle) Z|2\phi\rangle Z|4\phi\rangle = \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_e a_x|x\rangle |0\rangle|2\phi\rangle |4\phi\rangle + 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_o a_x|x\rangle |0\rangle Z|2\phi\rangle Z|4\phi\rangle + \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_e a_x|x\rangle e^{i(2\phi)}|1\rangle |2\phi\rangle |4\phi\rangle - 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_o a_x|x\rangle e^{i(2\phi)}|1\rangle Z|2\phi\rangle Z|4\phi\rangle
$

After the Z measurement of the first $|\phi\rangle$:

(+1) :
$ Z_{+} = 
\sum_e a_x|x\rangle |0\rangle|2\phi\rangle |4\phi\rangle + 
\sum_o a_x|x\rangle |0\rangle Z|2\phi\rangle Z|4\phi\rangle$

(-1) :
$
Z_{-} = 
\sum_e a_x|x\rangle |1\rangle |2\phi\rangle |4\phi\rangle - 
\sum_o a_x|x\rangle |1\rangle Z|2\phi\rangle Z|4\phi\rangle$

Where, $Z_{m}$ means the state after getting the result m of Z measurement.

If the result of the first measurement is +1, which means the rotation is successfully applied, then other states should be discarded by measuring them in the X basis(here we just ignore the state $|\phi\rangle$):

$Z_{+} = 
\sum_e a_x|x\rangle |2\phi\rangle |4\phi\rangle + 
\sum_o a_x|x\rangle Z|2\phi\rangle Z|4\phi\rangle = \\
\sum_e a_x|x\rangle (\frac{1+e^{i(4\phi)}}{2} |+\rangle + \frac{1-e^{i(4\phi)}}{2} |-\rangle)|4\phi\rangle + 
\sum_o a_x|x\rangle (\frac{1-e^{i(4\phi)}}{2} |+\rangle + \frac{1+e^{i(4\phi)}}{2} |-\rangle)Z|4\phi\rangle = \\
\sum_e a_x|x\rangle (\frac{1+e^{i(4\phi)}}{2} |+\rangle + \frac{1-e^{i(4\phi)}}{2} |-\rangle)(\frac{1+e^{i(8\phi)}}{2} |+\rangle + \frac{1-e^{i(8\phi)}}{2} |-\rangle) + \\
\sum_o a_x|x\rangle (\frac{1-e^{i(4\phi)}}{2} |+\rangle + \frac{1+e^{i(4\phi)}}{2} |-\rangle)(\frac{1-e^{i(8\phi)}}{2} |+\rangle + \frac{1+e^{i(8\phi)}}{2} |-\rangle) = \\
(\frac{1+e^{i(4\phi)}}{2}\frac{1+e^{i(8\phi)}}{2}\sum_e a_x|x\rangle + \frac{1-e^{i(4\phi)}}{2}\frac{1-e^{i(8\phi)}}{2}\sum_o a_x|x\rangle) |+\rangle |+\rangle + \\
(\frac{1+e^{i(4\phi)}}{2}\frac{1-e^{i(8\phi)}}{2}\sum_e a_x|x\rangle + \frac{1-e^{i(4\phi)}}{2}\frac{1+e^{i(8\phi)}}{2}\sum_o a_x|x\rangle) |+\rangle |-\rangle + \\
(\frac{1-e^{i(4\phi)}}{2}\frac{1+e^{i(8\phi)}}{2}\sum_e a_x|x\rangle + \frac{1+e^{i(4\phi)}}{2}\frac{1-e^{i(8\phi)}}{2}\sum_o a_x|x\rangle) |-\rangle |+\rangle + \\
(\frac{1-e^{i(4\phi)}}{2}\frac{1-e^{i(8\phi)}}{2}\sum_e a_x|x\rangle + \frac{1+e^{i(4\phi)}}{2}\frac{1+e^{i(8\phi)}}{2}\sum_o a_x|x\rangle) |-\rangle |-\rangle
$

With the equation: $\frac{1+e^{i(\theta)}}{2} = \cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$ and $\frac{1-e^{i(\theta)}}{2} = -i\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$

Then we have:

$Z_{+} = e^{i(6\phi)}\\
(\cos{2\phi} \cos{4\phi}\sum_e a_x|x\rangle - \sin{2\phi} \sin{4\phi} \sum_o a_x|x\rangle) |+\rangle |+\rangle + \\
((-i)\cos{2\phi} \sin{4\phi}\sum_e a_x|x\rangle + (-i)\sin{2\phi} \cos{4\phi} \sum_o a_x|x\rangle) |+\rangle |-\rangle + \\
((-i)\sin{2\phi} \cos{4\phi} \sum_e a_x|x\rangle + (-i)\cos{2\phi} \sin{4\phi} \sum_o a_x|x\rangle) |-\rangle |+\rangle + \\
(-\sin{2\phi} \sin{4\phi} \sum_e a_x|x\rangle + \cos{2\phi} \cos{4\phi} \sum_o a_x|x\rangle) |-\rangle |-\rangle
$

So I am stuck here, why these states after $X\otimes X$ measurement of the second and third magic state register are equal to perform a multi Pauli rotation?